# How to get Meteor Autoform to not insert form-control into afFieldInput?

Tags: meteor

When I use Autoform's `afFieldInput` it always wants to add a `form-control` class to whatever input field `afFieldInput` is defining. `form-control` sets the width to 100%, which is NOT what you want for a radio button...

This is what part of my schema looks like:

```
  propertyInfo: {
    type: Object
  },
  "propertyInfo.area" : {
    type: String,
    optional: false,
    label: "Location of Property *"
  },
```

And this is my radio button:

```
{{> afFieldInput class="track-initial-info-change" type="radio" template="" name="propertyInfo.area" value="area1" checked="checked"}}
```

I want it to render out as this:

```
<input class="track-initial-info-change" type="radio" name="propertyInfo.area" value="area1" checked="checked">
```

But it always renders out as:

```
<input class="track-initial-info-change form-control" type="radio" name="propertyInfo.area" value="area1" checked="checked">
```

That added `form-control` completely screws up the look of the site. Any idea? I already specified the `template=` property to something blank.

**EDIT**

This is what I've tried so far:

**html**

```
{{> afFieldInput name="year" options=yearOptions noselect="true" radio="true"}}
```

**js**

```
UI.registerHelper("yearOptions", function() {
    return [
        {label: "2013", value: 2013},
        {label: "2014", value: 2014},
        {label: "2015", value: 2015}
    ];
});
```

**schema**

```
  year: {
    type: Number,
    optional: true
  },
```

So I've used `afFieldInput` to represent an entire radio group, but the actual rendering is all wrong. The radio button itself floats over and intersects the text of the label.

This is what is rendered - as you can see, the `input` part of the radio button should NOT be nested inside the `label` tag. The `label` tag should be on a separate line of the `input` tag.

```
<div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="2013" name="year" data-schema-key="year">
        2013
      </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="2014" name="year" data-schema-key="year">
        2014
      </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="2015" name="year" data-schema-key="year">
        2015
      </label>
</div>
```

Another issue with having it render an entire radio group is that radios often can't be visually grouped together:

```
<div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="2013" name="year" data-schema-key="year">
        2013
      </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="2014" name="year" data-schema-key="year">
        2014
      </label>
</div>
<!-- Insert code here for creating a bootstrap accordion that drops 
down with a text box input when only the 2014 radio button is checked. 
It could be asking for something that only applies to year 2014 
specifically. How could you do this if afFieldInput only represents 
an entire radio group and not an individual radio button? -->
<div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="2015" name="year" data-schema-key="year">
        2015
      </label>
</div>
```

BTW, this is what I'm trying to accomplish - check out the **Location of the Property** area of the form.

http://hpp.meteor.com/prices

Comment: I could be wrong but try `{{> afFieldInput class="track-initial-info-change" radio="true" name="propertyInfo.area" value="area1" checked="checked"}}`

From what I could work out from using the Docs the type is set by the schema being boolean. In the template for bootstrap-3 if the type is not radio/checkbox etc it will add the class. That change should force it to use the adRadio element which doesn't trigger the form-control class to be added.

Comment: Thanks for the try. `{{> afFieldInput class="track-initial-info-change" type="radio" radio="true" template="" name="propertyInfo.area" value="area1" checked="checked"}}` renders into `<input type="radio" value="area1" class="track-initial-info-change form-control" name="propertyInfo.area" required="" data-schema-key="propertyInfo.area">`

Comment: Ah well that's unfortunate. Have you got the full source code for your form and any schema your using too. Hubert OG is right that template="plain" will work but looking at the code https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/blob/master/templates/bootstrap3/bootstrap3.js#L61 you shouldn't need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoForm author here. Technically, Hubert OG's answer is correct, too, but the real issue is that you are specifying your own `type` attribute, so that overrides all of the default handling. You should remove `type` attribute and remove `template` attribute and remove `checked` attribute. Then add an `options` attribute with proper values, keep `radio=true`, and, if you want a default checked value, put that value in a `value` attribute.

The key concept to understand here is that your `afFieldInput` represents the radio *group*, not a single radio button.

Comment: Awesome - thanks! Uhhh... hmmm... the thing with representing an entire group is that the `name=` attribute of the radio group is the same, no matter how many radio button options there are. And each radio button would have a separate label and value as well. So say you've got 10 radio buttons and 10 different labels and 10 different values for those radio buttons. But all of them share the same `name` attribute and only ONE entry in SimpleSchema.

I think where I'm confused is how would you specify each individual label and value if you had to do it all with only one `afFieldInput` helper.

Comment: oh, oh, oh. I just re-read the docs and it appears that you added more examples of how to specify options about the same time you answered this post, haha. Ok, awesome, I'll give it a go and post my results!

Comment: I still can't figure it out. The examples in the docs all point to your basic select dropdown, but there are no examples for radio buttons. Radio buttons have two parts - the circular button and the label, and they need to be defined seperately. It doesn't make sense to have `afFieldInput` to represent and render an entire radio group. Please see my example in the updated OP.

Comment: The default template is "bootstrap3" and will look fine if you are using bootstrap 3. If you aren't, or if you need different rendering, then you most likely need a custom template. You can try adding `template="plain"` attribute first, and your own classes, but if that doesn't meet your needs, you'll need to make your own template. The point about being unable to insert content between radio controls makes sense. You can submit a github issue and maybe it can be supported. But you can also just use normal markup within the form, so copy/paste your HTML example into a form should work.

Comment: I'm currently using Bootstrap 3 and I'm still getting an incorrect look since the radio input tags are rendered as being nested inside the label tags instead of being outside them. At this point it's a bit hard to discern whether I'm just doing it wrong or if AutoForm is acting weird.

Comment: Inputs inside labels is correct for bootstrap 3. See the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls). You might have some custom label CSS that is overriding the bootstrap styling.

Comment: Ah crap. I tried this code in Bootply and it was working perfectly. Sigh... I've got some CSS weirdness going on. BTW would you mind taking a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752694/any-way-to-have-simple-schema-in-meteor-validate-a-specific-array-index

Answer (score 0):

The `form-control` class is a part of the default `bootstrap3` template. To remove it, you need to use a different template, one that doesn't set this class. The purest one is `plain`, so just set it in your helper:

```
{{> afFieldInput template='plain' ... }}
```

Note that setting template value to the blank string won't work, as you need to pass a valid template name to override the default value. Check out [this part of the documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#templates) for build-in templates.

Comment: Thanks Hubert. Normally I wouldn't have any issues with this, but reading the changelog for Autoform: `0.2.2 - Don't include form-control class on radio buttons and check boxes` AutoForm is currently on 0.14.0, so I have a feeling that this is something that should have already been addressed without having to change the template to plain for each radio button. Basically, I'm using Autoform wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and the radio went back to normal. BUT this shouldn't be considered an actual answer because I'm still probably using Autoform wrong.

```
        <div class="form-inline">
          {{> afFieldInput class="track-initial-info-change" type="radio" radio="true" template="" name="propertyInfo.area" value="area1" checked="checked"}}
          <label class="label-to-bold-if-checked">
            Campbell, Cupertino, East Palo Alto, Fremont, Los Altos, Los Gatos, Menlo Park, Milpitas, Mountain View, Newark, Palo Alto, San Jose, Santa Clara, Saratoga, Sunnyvale, Union City
          </label>
        </div>
```