# Any way to have Simple Schema in Meteor validate a specific array index?

Tags: meteor

From what I understand in the docs, you can define your schema like this:

```
MySchema = new SimpleSchema({

    //This says that the addresses key is going to contain an array

    addresses: {
        type: [Object], 
    },

    // To indicate the presence of an array, use a $:

    "addresses.$.street": {
        type: String,
    },
    "addresses.$.city": {
        type: String,
    }

});
```

Ok, I get this part. But what if I wanted to validate the contents in a specific array index? I want something like this:

```
MySchema = new SimpleSchema({

    //This says that the itemsOrdered key is going to contain an array

    itemsOrdered: {
        type: [Object], 
    },

    // Here I want to validate certain indexes in the array.

    "itemsOrdered.0.sku": {
        type: String
    },
    "itemsOrdered.0.price": {
        type: Number
    },

    "itemsOrdered.1.sku": {
        type: String
    },
    "itemsOrdered.1.price": {
        type: Number
    },
    "itemsOrdered.1.quantity": {
        type: Number
    },
    "itemsOrdered.2.sku": {
        type: String
    },
    "itemsOrdered.2.price": {
        type: Number
    },
    "itemsOrdered.2.customerNotes": {
        type: String
        optional: true
    }

});
```

So here I'm trying to validate the values inside array index 0, 1, and 2. Each array index has a different item that has been ordered.

Normally I would use a hash table data structure, but for this purpose I need to preserve order which is why I'm using an array.

When I try to run this code I get an error **Cannot read property 'blackbox' of undefined**

Comment: Do you want the validation for the first element in the array to be different from the second? In the example you gave the validation is the same (street and city as Strings) so it could be implemented using a nested SimpleSchema. Having different validation schemas for the various indices of an array wouldn't be good design IMHO. If that's your goal maybe you can elaborate on your use case that makes you think this is required.

Comment: Ooops, sorry sorry, bad example on my part. I've updated the OP.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered custom validation?
https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/blob/master/README.md#custom-validation

According to the doc within the function the `key` property of `this` will provide the information you want. So you could have something like:

```
MySchema = new SimpleSchema({

    //This says that the itemsOrdered key is going to contain an array

    itemsOrdered: {
        type: [Object], 
    },

    // Here I want to validate certain indexes in the array.

    "itemsOrdered.$.sku": {
        type: String,
        custom: function () {
            var key = this.key,
                re = /\d+/;
            var index = Number(key.match(re)[0]);
            // Do some custom validation
        }
    },
    "itemsOrdered.$.price": {
        type: Number
    },

    "itemsOrdered.$.quantity": {
        type: Number,
        optional: true
    },

    "itemsOrdered.$.customerNotes": {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    }
});
```

Here I put the validation logic in the `sku` field since it's required.